# Transfer IntelliJ settings to to Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, settings

I want to easily transfer over all my custom shortcuts and IDE idiosyncrasies that are present in IntelliJ to Android Studio so I can begin my Android app development career without the headache of individually configuring each custom setting. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In order to transfer your existing settings from IntelliJ to Android Studio (or vice versa) select **File** -> **Manage IDE Settings** -> **Export Settings...** and select an appropriate path. Then in the other IDE you wish to transfer the settings to, select **File** -> **Manage IDE Settings** -> **Import Settings** and locate the previously exported .jar settings file.

Comment: If I want to use both IDEs, can I symlink Android Studio's settings to IntelliJ settings? So they are always synchronized

Comment: @CLOVIS did you try to symlink with success?

Comment: @RJFares Nope. I created a repository on GitLab and added that with https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-settings-repository.html do NOT clone locally or you will get a lot of conflicts in your settings. If you give it the GitLab/GitHub/whatever URL directly it works fine. It doesn't save your plugin list, but it does save their settings, so you just have to remember which plugins you have, and all your settings will be synced.

Comment: @CLOVIS thanks, that what I ended up doing. It actually managed to import from android studio to phpstorm successfully

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the settings from IntelliJ (by clicking *File->Export Settings*), and then import them to Android Studio (with *File->Import Settings*).

The trick is you also need to **disable 'IDE settings sync' in IntelliJ**, because if it is enabled, the Export Settings action is hidden in the File menu.